# Three20.h file not found when building with xcodebuild

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I build my project(include subproject Three20) successfully using xcode GUI,but when I use xcodebuild,it failed with this below:

```
/Users/***/MyProject/Classes/ComposeSMSViewController.h:14:9: fatal error: 'Three20/Three20.h' file not found [1] #import <Three20/Three20.h> 1 error generated.
```

my Header Search Paths are $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20 and $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20 and Classes/Three20/Build/Products/three20
That works on GUI building but failed on xcodebuild.
How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should restart three20's install , it need several steps and make sure it's without mistake. Best regards.  It may help you:  http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support

Comment: thanks,after reinstall three20 with my project, problem solved!

Comment: execute  "python three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p path/to/your/project/project.xcodeproj Three20 --xcode-version=4"
 did the trick

Answer (score 2):

If it still doesn´t work (and an error like "Three20.h file not found" is shown), try setting "Skip Install" to "Yes" for all of the Three20 **dependencies** and **projects** in your app (except your main project): [graphically](http://forums.three20.info/discussion/17/three20-officially-supports-xcode-4-with-1.0.5/p1) . This onle creates an .ipa for your project, but not for your three20 projects.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue today by accident. I tried all the solutions I found online and it didn't work. I was pretty confident that the problem was within xcode because the app built fine on my boss's machine. Turns out my scheme name didn't match my target name. This was a result of duplicating a target, which automatically named my scheme to "myapp copy". When I matched the scheme name to the target name, everything worked fine and the three20.h file was found. Hope this helps anyone with similar circumstances.

Product-> Manage Schemes... and rename the file